# Unit testing with EF - why are my models always empty?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using VS unit testing on an MVC-5, EF-6 project.  For now, I just want to get my unit tests to work by having my methods connect to the actual database just like they normally would.  I've read a lot about whether or not you should mock the database for purposes of unit testing so it's not necessary to tell me your stance on that.

I have a unit test like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SelectAssessmentTypeWhenLoggedIn()
    {
        // Arrange - login (otherwise it won't let you do this)
        var c = new AccountController();
        c.Login("username", "password");//I'm not showing you the real ones
        var abc = new AssessmentBuilderController();

        // Act - call the SelectAssessmentType() method
        ActionResult result = abc.SelectAssessmentType();

        //Assert -  model should have 4 ATs in it
        Assert.AreEqual(((result as ViewResult).Model as IEnumerable<AssessmentType>).Count(), 4);
    }
```

When called from the application, the method always has 4 entries in its model (as it should btw).  But when run from the unit test, it always has 0.  Here's the method's code:

```
    private List<AssessmentType> GetAssessmentTypes()
    {
        using (var context = new CLASSContext()) {
            return context.AssessmentType.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I can debug the unit test and step through the code and see the context is created and the table is in the context and see the SQL statement to be executed *AND YET* the model (List of AssessmentTypes) has 0 entries afterward!  What is going on?

Comment: Are you sure you're querying the right database?  With file-based databases you need to make sure you're pulling from the right file, and it's possible your unit test project is pulling from a different file.

Comment: It's a SQL database.  I can see that `context` has all the database's tables in it.   How else would I be able to verify that it's querying the right database?  I did look in Web.Debug.config and changed its connection string to mirror the normal Web.config (in case unit tests use that?).  Still no results.

Comment: @DStanley you were right...context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString shows that it is actually connected to a localDB db, not SQL.  So what do I do about it now?  How do I make unit tests connect to the right db?

Comment: You typically don't connect to a DB in unit tests - you mock them either hard-coding data or using a file.  Unit tests are to validate business rules, not database results.  That said, changing the app.config in the _test project_ should work.

Comment: @DStanley thank you, that was it.  I didn't realize that it used App.config instead of Web.config.  Feel free to post that as the answer and I'll accept it.  (And yes, I know most people say you should mock the db but my company/I don't follow that philosophy.)

Comment: It's not just opinionated advice. A unit test tests a single *unit* of functionality, hence the name. If you're querying a DB, then you're not testing a single unit of functionality; you're integration testing, as in testing the integration between the DB and the code you're running. In other words, this isn't a thing that you get to just say "we follow a different philosophy". You're not unit testing unless you mock the DB.

Comment: Agree 100% with Chris - attaching to a DB in unit tests has several disadvantages - performance, reliability, scalability, etc. The main advantage is effort - it takes effort to mock the database. You have to decide if the benefit is worth the costs (knowing that the costs increase over time)

Comment: Normally yes, unit tests should not rely on anything outside of themselves.  But when it comes to the db, unit-testing puritanism breaks down.  I COULD mock a db to give test methods the same values that are already in the database--but to what avail?  And I'm not alone in my opinion.  [1](http://tinyurl.com/o96kr5n), [2 (second answer)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206539/unit-tests-and-databases-at-which-point-do-i-actually-connect-to-the-database), and [3](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2013/05/testing-on-toilet-dont-overuse-mocks.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test projects have their own `app.config` configuration file - the connection string should be changed there.  Web.config is for *web* projects.